# Chrome refuses to load some PDFs in the browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, pdf, azure

Our web application lets users upload forms in pdf format (which are then stored in a Windows Azure Blob) and also lets them view them afterwards. What we want to is embed the pdf in a lightbox sort of thing. This is working totally fine in firefox once something like Acrobat Reader is installed but Chrome does absolutely nothing with it.

Even before getting to the embed part, just opening it in a tab doesn't work in Chrome. Entering the url in firefox works fine and it will ask if you want to save or open in Acrobat Reader. Opening a new tab in chrome and trying go to the url does absolutely nothing. The page just stays a blank white, and the name of the tab remains as 'New Tab'.

I checked what was going on in the Network tab of the browser console, and all I see is a supposedly successful GET call (code 200) but the status of it is cancelled.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. Same result unfortunately.

Comment: What content type are you setting on the blob? Double check that it's `application/pdf`.

Comment: Hey, turns out that's what the problem was. PDFs just get uploaded with a content type of application/octet-stream and Chrome doesn't seem able to figure out that it's actually a PDF (even though all the other browsers can?). Now I'm manually checking what the file extension is and setting the proper content-type. It doesn't seem like the best thing to do but I'm not sure what else to do.